# How to index multiple words as a single tokens in hibernate search?

Tags: search, solr, lucene, tokenize

I am using hibernate search with solr in my project and one of my use case would require data to be tokenized and indexed as follows:

One of my database field is a varchar and has values : New Road, Kings way (separated with commas)

I want the New Road and kings way to be used as a token rather than New, road, kings and way so that when i search for blah blah blah new road blah blah, it will show result with new road and if the search text contains new book, the result with new road won't show up.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can tokenize and search on that field using the `solr.PatternTokenizerFactory`
http://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Can you plz include some example with hibernate search annotation?

Comment: Ok i got to work it but have some problem. I am able to tokenize text for ex: **word1 word2, word3 word4** separately. Now when i search for **word1**, no result which is what is expected and when searched for **word1 word2**, 1 result, again as expected, but end users will be search for something like **blah blah word1 word2 blah blah** and now i am not getting any results, I am using hibernate query DSL, please suggest

Comment: not much experience with hibernate. You will need to go through the list of tokenizers/analyzers and look for the combination u need